# How do I permanently remove unneeded Nuget dependencies from ServiceStack?

Tags: servicestack

I just installed the ServiceStack Nuget package and it insists on installing database dependencies that I'm not using. I am only interested in the REST services. I found someone who was having the same issues and he claimed the typical workarounds such as -force uninstall doesn't apply. Is there another package available or a suitable workaround?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Database dependency you're referring to is just a benign OrmLite dll. It has no affect to the runtime if it exists or not. OrmLite is included by default since the OrmLite AuthProvider is included in ServiceStack.

There currently isn't any NuGet package that doesn't depends on OrmLite, but you can simply hand-pick the dlls out of the `/packages` folder and copy them and reference them manually.

Comment: Thanks. Please see my other question about configuration error.